# Paginating Octokit (GitHub API) repository search results

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

I'm experiencing a somewhat baffling issue with the Octokit GitHub API client related to repository searches. Using the `search_repos` method I can search for repositories by for instance language no problem:

```
repos = client.search_repos 'language:csharp'
```

This returns the default number of 100 repositories associated with the C# language. Great. However, I run into problems when trying to *paginate* the results, as demonstrated here:

repos = client.search_repos 'language:csharp', :page => 2

This returns the *first* page of results, despite it being apparent `:page` is one of the available options (per the Octokit source code and documentation, the former of which is shown here):

```
  # Search repositories
  #
  # @param query [String] Search term and qualifiers
  # @param options [Hash] Sort and pagination options
  # @option options [Fixnum] :page Page of paginated results
  # @option options [Fixnum] :per_page Number of items per page
  ...
  # @see http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories
  def search_repositories(query, options = {})
    search "/search/repositories", query, options
  end
  alias :search_repos :search_repositories
```

Any ideas? I've tried other variations but have concluded this is just a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by upgrading to the latest version of Octokit. The switch away from Hashie:Mash to Sawyer requires a bit of refactoring but otherwise everything is working great.